# Extract query fingerprints and tables from large log files using pt-query-digest

Tags: mysql, logs

I tried to parse a large log file using pt-query-digest but it gives "Out of memory!" when I try to read the file. I have 3GB RAM, 40GB empty space on HDD, the file is 20GB. I did not found anything in the documentation about memory.

I reduce the command at:

```
pt-query-digest --group-by fingerprint --print --no-report /path/to/largeLogFile.log
pt-query-digest --table-access /path/to/largeLogFile.log
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I extract the query fingerprints from a large log file generated by general_log ?
2. How can I extract all the tables that were used ?

**Edit:**
Tried @DTest --sample option (with 2 and 1), but the result is the same. Just before it reaches 50% memory in htop it dies every time (see screnshoot): [image]

I did an strace just before it dies I get:

```
read(3, "phone from teams as t ri"..., 4096) = 4096
mremap(0x5b27a000, 1543499776, 1543503872, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap2(NULL, 1543503872, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
brk(0x64c2d000)                         = 0x8c2e000
mmap2(NULL, 1543634944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x5b07a000
munmap(0x5b07a000, 548864)              = 0
munmap(0x5b200000, 499712)              = 0
mprotect(0x5b100000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1543503872, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
write(2, "Out of memory!\n", 15Out of memory!
)        = 15
munmap(0x5b27a000, 1543499776)          = 0
... [output removed] ...
```

The only option I can think so far is splitting the file "bite size" pieces (let's say 20 files of 1GB each), digest them and merge the result.

Comment: Does the `pt-query-digest --group-by fingerprint --print --no-report /path/to/largeLogFile.log` run out of memory?

Comment: @DTest Yes, this was the first thing I tried, then I tried different combination of options --table-access, --no-report etc ... without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the manual again and after some tests I have found answer for 2/3 problems:

**0.** "Out of memory" - caused by incorrect file type ( `--type` ) specified to `pt-query-digest`. The log file is from general_log, pt-query-digest by default parse it as it was slow query log, and of course the data is loaded in memory until it find a pattern that is not there.
Corect usage:

```
pt-query-digest --type genlog --group-by fingerprint --print --no-report /path/to/largeLogFile.log
```

**2.** Extract tables used, the --table-access work as expected (if the type is correctly used)

```
pt-query-digest --type genlog --table-access /path/to/largeLogFile.log
```

**1.** Extract fingerprints. Still did not found the correct usage. Everything I tried prints the full query with spaces, tabs, parameters. I tried `--group by, --sample, --no-report, pt-query-fingerprint` ...

For question 1. I am trying to extract just the query fingerprint, nothing else but:

```
pt-query-digest --type genlog --fingerprints --group-by fingerprint --print --no-report /path/to/largeLogFile.log
```

prints something like:

```
update some_table set some_column=0 where another_column='some_value';
# Time: 120716 11:08:27
# Thread_id: 201
# Query_time: 0.000000  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use some_database;
insert into some_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1','val2','val2');
# Time: 120716 11:08:27
# Thread_id: 202
# Query_time: 0.000000  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
```

and:

```
pt-fingerprint --match-embedded-numbers /path/to/largeLogFile.log
```

prints something like:

```
?:ca:?a:cc???????????value_a??:c0:a8:f7:?f:???????value_b??:?:b0:?:fd:???????value_c??c:af:f7:?:?:?d??????value_d??:c0:a8:f7:?f:??value_e??c:af:f7:?:?:?d??????w' where col_a=? ? query update table_a set col_a=now(), col_b=?, col_c=?, col_d=?, col_e=?, col_f=?, col_g=?, col_h=? where col_i=? and col_j=? ? quit ? query commit ?
```

It gets it right for some queries, but for the most it fails :(

Still waiting for a solution for Q1.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use the `--sample` option:

```
pt-query-digest --sample 2 --print --no-report /path/to/largeLogFile.log
```

This would filter out all but the first 2 occurrences of a query fingerprint. `--no-report` removes the memory and cpu overhead of aggregating.